# Почему галп выдает ошибку при работе с vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gulp

Всем добрый день.

Пока только учусь работать с vue.js и столкнулся с проблемой. При сборке файлов, галп выдает ошибку синтаксиса:

> Gulp Tasks: The task 'compile' has failed.
>   Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`'

код:

```
template: `{
    <header>
        <h1 v-for="post in content">{{post.title}}</h1>
        <p v-for="post in content" class="lead">{{post.desc}}</p>
    </header>
}`,
```

Если написать в строку и заменить кавычки, то все работает

```
template: '{<header><h1 v-for="post in content">{{post.title}}</h1><p v-for="post in content" class="lead">{{post.desc}}</p></header>}'
```

но в таком случае, если кода будет много, придется искать нужный фрагмент в этой строке очень долго. Да и выглядит это не очень структурировано.

Подскажите, можно ли это как-нибудь исправить?

Comment: Я так думаю, что вот [это](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-es6-template-strings) вам должно помочь. Есть у меня мысль, что галп не умеет в строки ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решила установка бабел для галп

https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel